# конструкция ORDER BY число

Tags: mysql, sql

Что значит конструкция `ORDER BY число` в запросе MySQL?

Обычно `ORDER BY` используется в сочетании с именем столбца, по которому нужно отсортировать результирующий набор строк, а что значит, когда вместо имени столбца используется число?

Comment: порядковый номер столбца в выборке

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ORDER BY число` позволяет сортировать по номеру столбца. Этот синтаксис отмечен как не рекомендованный

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY число` использует порядковый номер столбца из строки `SELECT` при сортировке.

> Не рекомендуется использовать запросы с сортировкой по
>   номерам столбцов. Это связано с тем, что со временем структура таблицы
>   может измениться, например, в результате добавления/удаления столбцов.
>   Как следствие, запрос может давать совсем другую последовательность или вообще вызывать ошибку, ссылаясь на отсутствующий столбец.

Подробнее на [тут](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_simple_select_statement/page2.html) и [тут](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/12/27/sql-server-order-by-columnname-vs-order-by-columnnumber/).

Comment: Обоснование бредовое. Не стоит писать `SELECT *`. А если в запросе перечислить конкретные поля, то мы уже не зависим от модификации таблицы. Кроме того, `ORDER BY` по вычисляемым полям нужно использовать **только** по номеру, иначе вычислять будем дважды

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, если вычисление абсолютно одинаковое в select и в order by, неужели он не догадается вычислить один раз?

Comment: @Qwertiy С какого перепугу? А если используется какая-то вычисляюще-логирующая функция? Или, что-то типа `Random()`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Обоснование **не** бредовое. Вам сначала стоит почитать немного. Поэтому можете это сделать, например, [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445118/what-is-the-purpose-of-order-by-1-in-sql-select-statement) и [тут](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/12/27/sql-server-order-by-columnname-vs-order-by-columnnumber/). Таблица может меняться, как и количество столбцов в ней, поэтому такая нестрогая запись не рекомендуется.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Order by выполняется после SELECT. Поэтому можно использовать как алиас вычисляемого столбца, так и его номер.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, `update smth set f = random()` во все строки пишет одно и то же значение. UPDATE: Упс, это про sql server было, в mysql не так.

Comment: @Denis. Еще раз внимательно перечитайте мою фразу "**Не стоит писать** `SELECT *`. А если **в запросе перечислить конкретные поля**, то мы уже **не зависим** от модификации таблицы

Comment: @msi Про алиасы принимается. Но откуда-то у меня знание, что где-то ORDER BY не работал с алиасами? Вроде где-то натыкался

Comment: Думаю, что проверить это можно секунд за 5.